# How to restore dropdown to default value in Semantic-UI-React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, redux-form

In default `semantic-ui` we can do this option: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/commit/b4ae26d24f75886c3d5f6fc4f00e176f09705a13
But, how to do it in `semantic-ui-react`? Google nothing say about it, please, I need help.

What I'm trying to achieve:
I'm using `redux-form`. In my form present semantic component `<Form.Select multiple ....>` and after success submit - call to `redux-form`  method `reset`. All is fine, form is clear... but not dropdown/select field. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

`Semantic-ui-react` props `value` set to the current value of the field.

```
<Form.Select
                    name={input.name}
                    options={options}
                    label={label}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    search
                    multiple
                    selectOnBlur={selectOnBlur}
                    onFocus={::this.handleFocus}
                    onBlur={::this.handleBlur}
                    onChange={::this.handleChange}
                    defaultValue={defaultValue || []}
                    value={input.value}
                    loading={loading} />
```

Comment: how did you get the value of the Select Button? I'm struggling ... really struggling